# Ошибка в webView - canGoBack

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

При нажатии кнопки возврата (backward) в приложении оно крашится

```
package ru.com.example1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = "Test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webView_main);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://ya.ru");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onKeyDown");
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object
>   reference

Где закралась ошибка?

Comment: у вас WebView - глоабльынй, но при определение есть и локальный. Инициализация приходиться на локальный, глобальный остается Null. оттого и краш

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепишите метод `onCreate` на следующий. У вас определение webView дублируется.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webView_main);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://ya.ru");

}
```